# Поочередный вывод на экран слов из файла

Tags: c++

Написал код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input ("c:\\f.txt");
    string s;
    getline(input, s);

    cout << s << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Но он выводит только первый элемент из файла. А как сделать, чтобы при каждом нажатии на клавишу "А", на экран выводился +1 элемент?

Comment: Вы считали одну строчку и ничего с ней не сделали. Все работает так, как написано.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы он выводил первую строку из файла? Написал так:

cout << getline(f, line);

Но он вывел только "0". В чем проблема?

Comment: `getline` возвращает ссылку на `istream`, которая преобразуется к `bool`, который преобразуется к `int` и `0` выводится на экран.

Comment: ок, получился. Я просто не то выводил. А вот щас он показывает только первое слово, а как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу "А" он выводил по одному и остальные? На счет нажатия клавиши я знаю как сделать. Ты можешь только мне подсказать код для файла? Чтобы он выводил 2,3 и т.д string lines

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ifstream input("input.txt");
std::string s;
```

Прочитать одну **строчку**:

```
getline(input, s);
```

Прочитать одно **слово**:

```
input >> s;
```

---

Операторы `>>` и `<<` указывают направление действия: `<<` — запись в поток, `>>` — чтение из потока. Не забывайте, что можно открыть поток на чтение и запись одновременно:

```
std::stringstream stream(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
```

Comment: Смотри в код, где там ошибка? почему ничего не делает?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вывести весь файл на экран, надо либо считывать последовательно строки в цикле в какой-нибудь объект string, который сразу выводить на консоль, например так:

```
string str;
ifstream fs ("f.txt");

while (getline (fs, str)) cout << str << endl;
```

А можно и сразу весь файл непосредственно считать из поточного буфера в стандартный вывод

```
cout << fs.rdbuf() << endl;
```

**P.S.**
В связи с корректировкой вопроса. Если пишите в винде, то можно так (тестировано в VS)

```
#include <conio.h>        

........

while ( fs >> str ) {
    while(_getch() != 'a') ;
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: вот ваш код выводит все слова на экран, а как сделать так, чтобы при каждом нажатии на клавишу "A" он выводил поочередно слова? Я читал, что это можно сделать с помощью цикла, но как, не знаю. Поможете?

Comment: Блин, тогда почему в вопросе написано "построчное чтение из файла"?

Вот так пиши

    while (fs >> str) cout << str << endl;

Comment: он тоже самое, все выводит за 1 раз

Comment: Даю 10 минут на переформулировку вопроса, а то закрою его

Comment: исправил. Думаю так будет яснее

Comment: никто не ответит???